# Why am i getting Stream as System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream?

Tags: c#, resources, assemblies, stream

I have a part of code like this

```
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] names = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (string file in names)
        {
            if (file.EndsWith(".dtd"))
            {
                // attach to stream to the resource in the manifest
                  dtdStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
                  MessageBox.Show(dtdStream.ToString());
            }                
        }
```

i have all the dtd files under my Resources folder.Which has build type Embedded Resource.
Now when i Debug the code i am getting a message box  showing    System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream

But i want a Managed MemoryStream?
What is wrong in my code?
Thanks...

Comment: Why do you want a managed memory stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resources get compiled as part of the assembly (EXE or DLL), which means they gets loaded into unmanaged memory when the OS starts the process. This is the reason why any stream returned by `GetManifestResourceStream` must therefore be *unmanaged* (of type `UnmanagedMemoryStream`).

What's the problem with this, anyway? The interface of `MemoryStream` and `UnmanagedMemoryStream` are basically identical, and it's only the (hidden) functionality that differs, which shouldn't be of any consequence to you.

Comment: If possible can i get the stream returned by GetManifestResourceStream as managed? If yes then how?

Comment: @crazy_itgal: Yes, but it wouldn't be pretty, and would offer no advantages that I could envisage (and only create overhead). (For what exactly are you thinking it will help?) Anyway, the basic method would be to read the entired UnmanagedMemoryStream and write everything into a MemoryStream object.

Comment: If I need to read an image from resource stream, I will have to use UnmanagedMemoryStream to initialize BitmapImage, which only accepts MemoryStream as the parameter of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "by design" behavior and provides a faster access of memory.

Reference: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.definemanifestresource(VS.85).aspx