# .NET embedded resource, getting an IntPtr to the raw memory location for use in unmanaged code

Tags: .net, pinvoke, embedded-resource

I need to expose a `void*` and `ulong size` value to native code that points to a .NET embedded resource.

Now, I could allocate the memory myself and copy the data (using traditional methods), but these files may be large so I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Is there a way to point (via raw pointer) to the embedded resource directly? Either memory, or an offset that can be used to go to the .NET library directly on the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some tests, embedded resources are loaded as `UnmanagedMemoryStream`... So:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/917607/613130
UnmanagedMemoryStream stream = (UnmanagedMemoryStream)assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("DefaultNamespaceOfAssembly.FileName.jpg");
byte* ptr = stream.PositionPointer;
long length = stream.Length;
```

From comments in the reference source, the operation shouldn't allocate any memory (the pointer you get should be to the real resource that is loaded in memory). In fact, the `UnmanagedMemoryStream` doesn't free any memory on `Dispose()`.

Note that the `ulong size` you asked is a little fishy... I hope you are sure of it. The `unsigned long` of VC++ isn't `long`, and the `size_t` is a `ulong` only at 64 bits, and is a `uint` at 32 bits.

Comment: You JUST saved my ass on another question and here you are, AGAIN! Let me buy you a beer already... ;)

About the ```ulong```, I don't actually know about the struct yet, so I guessed on the size.